# htaccess Redirect non.www and www. to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, subdirectory

I tried different ways in htaccess but none worked. I have 2 domains and 1 webshosting.

I want that any user who types in `website_1.com` or `www.website_1.com` should be redirected to `www.website_1.com/abc` and any user who types `website_2.com` or `www.website_2.com` should be redirected to `www.website_2.com/xyz`

How could I put that in one single htaccess file? My current htaccess file:

```
#Redirect from non-www. to www.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website_1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website_1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website_2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website_2.com/$1 [R=301,L]


#Redirect specific Domain to subfolder

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website_1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc/$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website_2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xyz/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xyz/$1
```

Comment: Thank you for editing, it looks much better now as its easier to read it!

Comment: When I checked both domains today, it seems to work! Maybe yesterday I had an issue with the browser cache. But is this content of the htaccess file the best way, or would there be a better, shorter way? Is it google friendly?   Thank you.

Comment: Furthermore Im just wondering if this is a 301 or a 302 redirection? Since its not written in the code.

Comment: Its strange, with Google Chrome it doesnt seem to work. But with Firefox and Internet Explorer it works. When I open website_1.com with Chrome, its okay, but when I open website_2.com it redirects me to www.website_2/abc  instead of www.website_2/xyz   ... someone knows that issue with Google Chrome ?